# Stripe payment method. Use card [split-form] not working. Can't get card number expiry and cvc number

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, stripe-payments

I am implementing stripe with react and node.
but I am not getting these values

```
    <CardNumberElement/>
    <CardExpiryElement/> 
    <CardCvcElement/>
```

Without its value can't get token and can't charge money.

if I only use cardElement that's work but cardElement is a one-line input field but I want to split it. so that's why I used CardNumberElement , CardExpiryElement, and CardCvcElement for splitting.
backend code is perfect but the error is inside frontend because we can't pass values perfectly for creating the stripe token for the payment.

**Frontend Code:**

```
import React from "react";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import {
    Elements,
    CardElement,
    useStripe,
    useElements,
    CardNumberElement,
    CardExpiryElement,
    CardCVCElement,
    injectStripe,
    StripeProvider,
    CardCvcElement
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import axios from "axios";
import { ServiceBooking } from "../../services/service-booking"


const CheckoutForm = ({ success }) => {
    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();

    const handleSubmit = async event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let number = elements.getElement(CardNumberElement);
        let cvc = elements.getElement(CardCvcElement);
        console.log("farrukh",number)
        const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
            type: "card",
            card: {
                number: number,
                exp_month: 4,
                exp_year: 2021,
                cvc: cvc,
              }
        });

        if (!error) {
            const { id } = paymentMethod;

            try {
                const data = await ServiceBooking.charge(id, 1099);
                console.log(data);
                success();
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <form
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            style={{ maxWidth: "400px", margin: "0 auto" }}
        >
            <h2>Price: $10.99 USD</h2>
            <CardNumberElement/>
            <CardExpiryElement/> 
            <CardCvcElement/>
            <button type="submit" disabled={!stripe}>
                Pay
      </button>
        </form>
    );
};

// you should use env variables here to not commit this
// but it is a public key anyway, so not as sensitive
const stripePromise = loadStripe("pk_test_wSvr6guTJvkKmv21jVqVd2D20049BVPKHP");

const Checkout = () => {
    const [status, setStatus] = React.useState("ready");

    if (status === "success") {
        return <div>Congrats on your empanadas!</div>;
    }

    return (
          <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
              <CheckoutForm
                  success={() => {
                  setStatus("success");
                 }}
              />
          </Elements>
    );
};

export default Checkout;
```

**Backend Code:**

```
router.post(
    "/charge",
    asyncHandler(async function (req, res) {
        const { id, amount } = req.body;

  try {
    const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount,
      currency: "USD",
      payment_method: id,
      confirm: true
    });

    console.log(payment);

    return res.status(200).json({
      confirm: "abc123"
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: error.message
    });
  }
    })
);
```

I have tried but could not charge (payment) successfully

Answer (score 3):

in Stripe.js, you would just need to pass the `CardElement` to the `stripe.createPaymentMethod` call. You do not need the card number nor you can get the card number due to security reason.

```
let number = elements.getElement(CardNumberElement);
...
const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
            type: "card",
            card: number
        });
```

You may ask how do I pass in the `cvc` and `expiry date`? The answer is that you don't have to, Stripe.js will automatically locate the CVC and expiry input automatically in the same page.

See reference at https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your front-end code. For a split form to work, you should use three different (card) keys  under .createPaymentMethod to catch the CardNumberElement, CardExpiryElement, and CardCvcElement respectively

```
  .createPaymentMethod(
    {
      type: 'card',
      card: elements.getElement(CardNumberElement),
      card: elements.getElement(CardExpiryElement),
      card: elements.getElement(CardCvcElement),
    }
```

**Your Frontend Code should look like this:**

```
import React from "react";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import {
    Elements,
    CardElement,
    useStripe,
    useElements,
    CardNumberElement,
    CardExpiryElement,
    CardCVCElement,
    injectStripe,
    StripeProvider,
    CardCvcElement
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import axios from "axios";
import { ServiceBooking } from "../../services/service-booking"


const CheckoutForm = ({ success }) => {
    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();

    const handleSubmit = async event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
          type: 'card',
          card: elements.getElement(CardNumberElement),
          card: elements.getElement(CardExpiryElement),
          card: elements.getElement(CardCvcElement),
        });

        if (!error) {
            const { id } = paymentMethod;

            try {
                const data = await ServiceBooking.charge(id, 1099);
                console.log(data);
                success();
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <form
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            style={{ maxWidth: "400px", margin: "0 auto" }}
        >
            <h2>Price: $10.99 USD</h2>
            <CardNumberElement/>
            <CardExpiryElement/> 
            <CardCvcElement/>
            <button type="submit" disabled={!stripe}>
                Pay
      </button>
        </form>
    );
};

// you should use env variables here to not commit this
// but it is a public key anyway, so not as sensitive
const stripePromise = loadStripe("pk_test_wSvr6guTJvkKmv21jVqVd2D20049BVPKHP");

const Checkout = () => {
    const [status, setStatus] = React.useState("ready");

    if (status === "success") {
        return <div>Congrats on your empanadas!</div>;
    }

    return (
          <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
              <CheckoutForm
                  success={() => {
                  setStatus("success");
                 }}
              />
          </Elements>
    );
};

export default Checkout;
```

Comment: I don't think a JS object can accept 3 values for the same key. Your example has 3 values for "card": `card: elements.getElement(CardNumberElement),
          card: elements.getElement(CardExpiryElement),
          card: elements.getElement(CardCvcElement)`

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone coming up with this issue in 2022. I was having a similar set up as OP and the answer is [here on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gW8b0Y6Ae8o). You can use the method `.confirmCardPayment` taking any of the elements. Something like:

```
(token) => {
    stripe?.confirmCardPayment(token, {
      payment_method: {
        card: elements?.getElement(CardNumberElement),
        billing_details: {
          name: "Leandro",
        },
      },
    });
  }
```

it will still validate all fields. Testing in the sandbox, I was passing like so but testing with leaving CVC empty, and stripe API was rejecting.

Comment: confirmCardPayment has different behavior from createPaymentMethod, though. I just want to create a payment method.